# split() is not giving the expected outcome

Tags: javascript

I'm having problems why my .split() function.
somehow when i splay my line the first [0] element in the array can be accessed but the 2nd [1] can't

I have the following string:

```
 ,{"relationID":"000001","recID":"1d2712eb-4f08-4b4f-b6e9-600c9631b503"
```

And the code below is how i try to split this (tempArray contains a x number of strings like the above):

```
var templine = tempArray[i].substr(1, tempArray[i].length);
//alert(templine);
var line = templine.split(',');
var s1 = line[0].split('"')[3];
var s2 = line[1].split('"')[3];
```

when i use alert(s1) or alert(s2) i do get the value however, the folowing error always occurs on the last line (var s2):

> caught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

this causes the rest of my script to crash and it won't finish what it's supposed to, displaying an empty page.

My question, what is going wrong here? why does s1 function properly and s2 which is exactly the same except for the index of the line array crash my script.

I want to **emphasise** when i use the alert function to check the value of my variable s1 and s2 they do contain the right value.

EDIT:
maybe a nice bonus since there might be an easyer way.
after I've gotten the values s1 and s2 i want to put them in a map like so:

```
map[s2] = s1;
```

as you can probably tell the string i use is the result of splitting 1 humongous string on ('}'). the code displayed here is what i do when looping trough this array.

Comment: As the error states, `line[1]` is undefined.

Comment: I have no issues running your code as it is.

Comment: no issue running your code

Comment: @forgivenson how can it be undefined it is obvious it exists, i even get a value if i try alert(line[1]);

Comment: @Vache i know it should work perfectly, but somehow it just doesn't it even gives me the results i want but it throws that darn exception and it then simply shows an empty page.

Comment: I guess you better make a jsFiddle of it.

Comment: @VincentAdvocaat If it says it is undefined, then it doesn't exist. I'm guessing you see the value from a different iteration of that loop than the one that produces the error. Since you haven't given us the rest of your code and test data (such as the contents of `tempArray`), we can't know for sure what is happening. However, from reading through your code, I can see that it is possible for `templine` to end up with no `,` in it, which would result in `line[1]` being `undefined`, and produce that error.

Comment: you were right about the unexpected input @forgivenson
My very last line contains a ; which is kinda stupid of me forgetting to filter that last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can only be caused by a attempt to access element on the array that is really `undefined`. Probably your input is not what you are expecting.

Check if `line.length > 1` before you try to read those indexes of the array.

As it seems to be a JSON, may be you should try to parse the JSON, it would make your code more readable and reliable. Check `JSON.parse` browser compatibility before using it (IE8+).

For example:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{ "field1": "value1", "field2": "value2" }');

var s1 = data['field1'];
var s2 = data['field2'];
```

Hope I've helped.

Comment: It sure is what i was looking for, yet an error still remains, probably what @forgivenson said about my data not being as i expected.
EDIT not probably, it actually was unexpected input.

Comment: try at twitter, it is on my profile, but i really don't have a lot of free time. you can always ask here, and, if I know how to help, I'll give a try

Comment: Nvm i already figured it out, with parsing a complete jason object. thanks anyway, i really apreciate it :)